# Extending the user model: SimpleLazyObject error when using user.is_authenticated()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

So, to begin, I have extended the default Django user to include a user avatar. I'm now beginning to think if I have done this as good as I could have done, as although the user_avatar field is now referencable - I'm receiving some issues at various points.

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile')
    user_avatar = models.ImageField(storage=site_media_upload_location, null=True, blank=True)

class Post(models.Model):

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('published', 'Published'),
    )

    POST_TYPES = (
        ('news', 'News'),
        ('feature', 'Feature'),
        ('review', 'Review'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')

    author = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='blog_posts')

    body = models.TextField()
    lead_in = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')

    #These next items shall contain our development information for game reviews - this is much like the lead_in:
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='')
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='')
    developer = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='')
    release = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True, related_name='post_likes')

    #Out blog layout dictates each featurette has up to three scrolling images associated to it:
    image_scroll_1 = models.ImageField(storage=site_media_upload_location, null=True, blank=True)
    image_scroll_2 = models.ImageField(storage=site_media_upload_location, null=True, blank=True)
    image_scroll_3 = models.ImageField(storage=site_media_upload_location, null=True, blank=True)

    type = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=POST_TYPES,default='review')

    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default='draft')
    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=10)

    wrap_header = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')
    wrap_up = models.TextField(default='')
    disclaimer = models.TextField(default='')

    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()
    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return the state title of the post"""
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Get absolute_url path specific to this post."""
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args = [self.publish.year, self.publish.strftime('%m'), self.publish.strftime('%d'), self.slug])

    def get_like_api_toggle_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:like_api_toggle', args = [self.publish.year, self.publish.strftime('%m'), self.publish.strftime('%d'), self.slug])

    def get_image(self):
        """Get upload_to path specific to this photo."""
        return self.image.url
```

views.py:

```
class PostLikeAPIToggle(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, post=None, year=None, month=None, day=None, format=None):
        post = self.kwargs.get("post")
        obj = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        updated = False
        liked = False

        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            if user in obj.likes.all():
                liked = False
                obj.likes.remove(user)
            else:
                liked = True
                obj.likes.add(user)
            updated = True

        data = { 'updated': updated, 'liked': liked }
        return Response(data)
```

When checking that this user is authenticated (the `request.user.is_authenticated()`) I receive the following error:

```
'UserProfile' instance expected, got <SimpleLazyObject: <User: default_user>>
```

I've tried a number of things, such as:

```
user = self.request.userprofile.user

user = self.request.user.userprofile
```

and also:

```
if user.userprofile.is_authenticated():
```

but to no avail. I'm wondering if anyone can quickly provide some pro-tips on how to navigate around this issue...

Full traceback:

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  489.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  449.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  486.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Developer/Django/eos/blog/views.py" in get
  28.                 obj.likes.remove(user)

File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in remove
  949.             self._remove_items(self.source_field_name, self.target_field_name, *objs)

File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in _remove_items
  1145.                 self.through._default_manager.using(db).filter(filters).delete()

File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  782.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  800.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1261.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1281.                     current_negated, allow_joins, split_subq)

File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1287.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1190.             self.check_related_objects(field, value, opts)

File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in check_related_objects
  1090.                     self.check_query_object_type(v, opts, field)

File "/Users/MichaelJRoberts/anaconda/envs/snakes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in check_query_object_type
  1065.                     (value, opts.object_name))

Exception Type: ValueError at /blog/api/2013/08/28/final-fantasy-xiv-realm-reborn/like/
Exception Value: Cannot query "michaeljroberts": Must be "UserProfile" instance.
```

Comment: Please show the complete traceback and the `Post` model.

Comment: Hi @Alistair - please find above the updated details you requested, thank you.

Comment: I think your error is in  `obj.likes.remove(user)` as it expects a `UserProfile` instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks ok:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
```

The traceback is showing you that the error is on this line

```
obj.likes.remove(user)
```

Your many-to-many field is to the `UserProfile` model, not the `User` model.

```
likes = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, ...)
```

Therefore you should be using the profile when you check/add/remove likes.

```
profile = user.userprofile
if profile in obj.likes.all():
    liked = False
    obj.likes.remove(profile)
else:
    liked = True
    obj.likes.add(profile)
updated = True
```